# Handling exceptions thrown by Spring @Async methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

In my Spring Boot app, I have a method that sends emails by making (blocking) HTTP calls to the SendGrid API. In some cases I call this method several times per request, so in order to mitigate the impact on the request thread, I call this method asynchronously by annotating it with `@Async`.

```java
public class EmailService {

    @Async
    public void send(String address, String subject, String body) {
        // make a HTTP call to SendGrid's API
    }
}

public class PasswordService {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    public void resetAll(String emailAddresses) {
        emailAddresses.forEach(email -> {
            emailService.send(email, "Your new password is", "open-sesame");   
        });
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handleException(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it bypasses the application's exception handling. If an exception is thrown by `emailService.send`, the global exception handler is not called, and therefore a 500 HTTP status is not returned to the client.

If I remove `@Async`, the global exception handlers is called as expected. **How can I call this method asynchronously, without bypassing the global exception handler?**

Comment: Not sure I follow. You're scheduling sth to run in a bg thread, and then expecting the controller to wait until that bg work is complete? What was the point of scheduling to the bg in the first place, if the original thread is still supposed to be blocked?

Comment: The answer is that you cannot. You have no control over when the sending starts or ends. For instance, when the sending starts, the user could have already received a success response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems I didn't do a great job of explaining the problem. I've tested the solution below and am satisfied that it meets my requirements

```java
public class EmailService {

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<?> send(String address, String subject, String body) {
        try {
            // make a HTTP call to SendGrid's API
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class PasswordService {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    public void resetAll(String emailAddresses) {

        var emailTasks = emailAddresses.stream()
            .map(email -> emailSendingService.send(email, "Your new password is", "open-sesame"))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);

        // wait for all the calls to emailService to complete, throw an
        // exception if any of them fail
        CompletableFuture.allOf(emailTasks).join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to process asynchronous tasks but in case of errors make the error handling synchronous and notify the user.

Without changing your logic, this seems impossible per definition. You make the async call because you don't want the user to wait for the heavy processing, i.e. the response is faster than the heavy process but you want to wait if it's error which you cannot foresee. I think you have to change your way to handle that case which requires to rethink your logic.

A more complex approach would be to process the error handling via WebSocket connection or constant polling from client to server, where the error handler notifies the user. This would mean that the user gets the error delayed.

An easier approach would be to allow the user to run the process again "Dont have a mail? send mail again" or something like that.